# The css class disappear when i change to another navigation system

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'll try to explain what I need:

When I enter the index.php page the button LINK_1 is active. When I switch to LINK_2 this becomes active.
I only have one index.php page where only include parts of external pages in PHP.

Page_1
[image]
With the code I found this is working.

**HTML:**

```
<menu id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-lg"></i><p class="desc_menu">BTN_1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?nav=1" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg"></i><p class="desc_menu">BTN_2</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:xpto@xpto.com" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg">EMAIL</i><p class="desc_menu">COMUNICATIONS</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="exit.php" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-lg"></i><p class="desc_menu">EXIT</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</menu>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
    .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
        $(this).addClass("activ");
      })
  });
```

I have two navigation systems. The main menu at the top where I navigate using the global variable "nav" and then I have another system which use the global variable "op".

Page_2
[image]
When I click the (index.php?nav=1&p=1, 2 or 3) the class activ in button LINK_2 disappears. I need it to continue active.
What I'm not doing well for this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you click index.php?nav=1&op=1, is the page at index.php?nav=1&op=1 loaded? Or it does not reload because you have a preventDefault() there for the click event?

I assume the page at index.php?nav=1&op=1 is loaded when you click. In this case, you need to change your JavaScript to parse the nav query out, find the link with that nav number, and set it to be active. This should be inside the click handler of the green links.

Comment: It's just one page. I use the php function "include" to call php pages. These are included when i click on the buttons.

Comment: check if your browser's address becomes index.php?nav=1&op=1 after you clicks the first button. If it does, then your javascript will not work because pgurl is index.php?nav=1&op=1 not index.php?nav=1.